# Nodejs setInterval and run first immediatly not after interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I try to implement a loop in my noejs app that will always wait between the tasks. For this I found the setInterval function and I thought it is the solution for me. But as I found out, the first Interval, means the very first action also wait until the interval is ready. But I want that the first action runs immediatly and then each action with the given interval.
In arry scope:
myArray[0] starts immediatly while myArray[1..10] will start with Interval waiting time.

I tried it with:

```
function rollDice(profilearray, browserarray, url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var i = 0;
    const intervalId = setInterval(
      (function exampleFunction() {
        console.log(profilearray[i].profil);
        //########################################################################

        createTestCafe("localhost", 1337, 1338, void 0, true)
          .then((tc) => {
            testcafe = tc;
            runner = testcafe.createRunner();
            inputStore.metaUrl = url;
            inputStore.metaLogin = teamdataarray[0].email;
            inputStore.metaPassword = teamdataarray[0].password;
            inputStore.moderator = profilearray[i].profil;
            inputStore.message = profilearray[i].template;
            inputStore.channelid = profilearray[i].channelid;
          })
          .then(() => {
            return runner
              .src([__basedir + "/tests/temp.js"])
              .browsers(browserarray)
              .screenshots("", false)
              .run()
              .then((failedCount) => {
                testcafe.close();

                if (failedCount > 0) {
                  console.log(profilearray[i].profil);
                  console.log("No Success. Fails: " + failedCount);
                  //clearInterval(intervalId);
                  //reject("Error");
                } else {
                  console.log(profilearray[i].profil);
                  console.log("All success");
                  //clearInterval(intervalId);
                  //resolve("Fertig");
                }
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            testcafe.close();
            console.log(profilearray[i].profil);
            console.log("Testcafe Error" + error);
            //clearInterval(intervalId);
            //reject("Error");
          });

        //######################################################################

        i++;
        console.log("Counter " + i);
        if (i === profilearray.length) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          resolve("Fertig");
        }
        return exampleFunction;
      })(),
      3000
    ); //15 * 60 * 1000 max time to wait (user input)
  });
}
```

The way I have done works bad because in the first action it will not start the testcafe. But in all other actions it will do.
Anybody knows a better way to do this?

Scope:
Give a array of data and for each array start testcafe with a given waiting time. 3 seconds up to 15 minutes. Because in some cases 15 Minutes is a long time I want to start the first one without any waiting time.
Iam open for any suggestion

Comment: Do you want to wait `x` seconds between the tasks, or do you want to call the task every `x` seconds, but only if the previous task is already finished?

Comment: no wonder, you use an IIFE, https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modern JavaScript `await` and `async` should be used instead of `then` and `catch`.

This will make many things easier, and the code becomes more readable. You e.g. can use a regular `for` loop to iterate over an array while executing asynchronous tasks within it. And use `try-catch` blocks in the same way as you would in synchronous code.

```js
// a helperfunction that creates a Promise that resolves after
// x milliseconds
function wait(milliseconds) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

async function rollDice(profilearray, browserarray, url) {
  for (let i = 0; i < profilearray.length; i++) { 
    // depending how you want to handle the wait you would create
    // the "wait"-Promise here
    // let timer = wait(3000)

    let testcafe = await createTestCafe("localhost", 1337, 1338, void 0, true);
    
    try {
      let runner = testcafe.createRunner();
      inputStore.metaUrl = url;
      inputStore.metaLogin = teamdataarray[0].email;
      inputStore.metaPassword = teamdataarray[0].password;
      inputStore.moderator = profilearray[i].profil;
      inputStore.message = profilearray[i].template;
      inputStore.channelid = profilearray[i].channelid;

      let failedCount = await runner.src([__basedir + "/tests/temp.js"])
        .browsers(browserarray)
        .screenshots("", false)
        .run()

      if (failedCount > 0) {
        // ...
      } else {
        // ...
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(profilearray[i].profil);
      console.log("Testcafe Error" + error);
    } finally {
      testcafe.close();
    }

    // Here you would wait for the "wait"-Promise to resolve:
    // await timer;
    // This would have similar behavior to an interval.

    // Or you wait here for a certain amount of time.
    // The difference is whether you want that the time the 
    // runner requires to run counts to the waiting time or not.
    await wait(3000)
  }

  return "Fertig"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare function before `setInterval`, run `setInterval(exampleFunction, time)` and then run the function as usual (`exampleFunction()`). May not be ideal to the millisecond, but if you don't need to be perfectly precise, should work fine.

Ask if you need further assistance

EDIT: now looking twice at it, why are you calling the function you pass as parameter to `setInterval` inside the `setInterval`?